# How is the following derived?

Tags: integration, power-series, laplace-transform

To give some context, I am viewing the following lecture which derives the Laplace Transform.

[Lec 19 | MIT 18.03 Differential Equations, Spring 2006](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZ2qulI6GEk&t=82s)

At the 6:40 mark, the lecturer seems to skip over how the continuous analogue of the following discrete power series is derived.

$$\sum_{0}^{\infty} a(n)x^n$$

Afterwards, the lecturer presents the following integral.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} a(t)x^tdt$$

I want to understand how the continuous analogue was derived as I am having a hard time of it myself.

(Disclaimer: I am an engineering student, not a mathematics student.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, the idea is that $\int$ is the continuous analog of $\sum$ (recall that the integral is the limit of a Riemann sum as the difference $\Delta x$ tends to zero). So, the continuous analog of $\sum_0^\infty a(n)x^n$ will naturally be $\int_0^\infty a(t)x^tdt$, as long as we appropriately extend the domain of $a$ to $[0,\infty)$ (not just the nonnegative integers). The idea that the lecturer is trying to get across here is that the Laplace transform is in a sense just the continuous analog of a power series.

Note that you still have issues of convergence, etc. to deal with, so this isn't strictly speaking rigorous.

Comment: Wouldn't the continuous analogue be $\sum_{0}^{\infty}a(t)x^t$ where $t$ equals $\delta t \times n$?

Comment: @vecohah why would it be? If we still have a sum, then we must have an indexing variable which takes on integer values, no matter what you call it: $n$ or $t$ or anything else. And if it is an indexing variable which only takes on integer values, then it is discrete by definition.

Comment: How would I express the discrete sum as a Riemann?

Comment: @vecohah sorry, I don't quite get your question. Can you rephrase?

Comment: Apologies, I am trying to convert $\sum_{0}^{\infty} a(n)x^n$ into a Riemann sum

Comment: @vecohah Why would you need to, how is that relevant?

Comment: I apologies as I have been all over the place in terms of my questions and I have failed to be articulate enough to convey exactly what it is I am having issues with, which is why I have posted a new question which asks the exact question I hope to get answered https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3366342/why-is-int-0-infty-ftxtdt-the-continuous-version-of-the-power-series

Comment: @vecohah: if you want to add to your question, **put that in your question body with an edit**. Do **not** ask a new question when it is in substance the same, although it does have new elaboration. I will say though that the extra elaboration is helpful, but it should not exist as a new question. It will be swiftly closed as duplicate very soon.

Comment: Is it something you have an answer to? as I have been trying to find an answer.

Comment: @vecohah reiterating that you have been trying very hard to find an answer is not going to help you find one, I'm afraid. Doesn't really matter how many times you reiterate the point, you're just beating a dead horse. It is quite annoying that you ignored the entirety of my previous two comments as well and just continued to beg for an answer.

Comment: Point taken, I would also like to thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you should not think in term of discrete analog. If you really want to then show  if the series converges for $|x|< r\le1$ $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a(n)x^n =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty a(n)(-\log(x))\int_n^\infty x^t dt=-\log(x) \int_0^\infty (\sum_{n \le t} a(n)) x^tdt$$

Comment: I was thinking about an explanation more along the lines of using a Riemann sum, is that possible?

Comment: no, what don't you like in my explanation

Comment: I find it hard to understand and hoped for an easier explanation

Comment: There is nothing hard to understand in what I wrote.

Comment: The part I am having trouble with is the introduction of the $-log(x)\int_{0}^{\infty}x^tdt$

Comment: Differentiate $x^t=e^{t \log x}$ wrt $t$ you'll find $\log (x) x^t$