# Why is $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t)x^tdt$ the continuous version of the power series $\sum_{0}^{\infty} f(n)x^n$?

Tags: integration, proof-verification, power-series

I am having trouble understanding why $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t)x^tdt$ is the continuous analogue of the power series $\sum_{0}^{\infty} f(n)x^n$.

as in my mind a continuous power series is the following

(1) $f(0)x^0 + f(dt)x^{dt} + f(2dt)x^{2dt} + .... $

not the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t)x^tdt$

(2) $dt(f(0)x^0 + f(dt)x^{dt} + f(2dt)x^{2dt} + ....) $

as it seems to just be a continuous power series multiplied by $dt$

So why is (2) a *"continuous analogue of a power series"* but (1) isn't ?

Comment: Do you have an example where this integral was called the "continuous version/analogue" of the power series? Or, do you have a specific definition of what this means? Analogues are a subjective notion at worst, and heavily context-dependent at best.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Relation_to_power_series

Comment: @TheoBendit under the section titled "Relation to power series" it states the "Replacing summation over n with integration over t, a continuous version of the power series becomes $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t)x^tdt$"

Comment: That being the case, I wouldn't put too much stock in understanding that particular phrase. I think there will be an answer to your question (which I don't have) involving some parallels between the Laplace transform and corresponding operations one can do with generating functions, but I don't think there's a specific meaning to the phrase. That is, I don't think it anyone can precisely, logically answer why one proposed function is an "analogue" over another function.

Comment: I ask this question as I have spent hours trying to understand why (1) is not a continuous power series despite whilst (2) is, which seems confusing.

Comment: I'm not a particularly dab hand with differentials, but I must confess that I'm sceptical of your usage of them here, in both (1) and (2). What does it mean to raise $x^{\mathrm{d}x}$? I personally don't know.

Comment: I believe I edited the question to correct the mistake.